# Смысл слова "некоторые"

Tags: значение-слов

Меня интересует, включает ли слово "некоторые" в себя и пустое подмножество. Например, если я скажу "некоторые коты едят спаржу", означает ли это, что обязательно должны быть коты, едящие спаржу или же высказывание допускает ситуацию, при которой не будет найден ни один кот, поедающий спаржу?

Comment: Вы задаёте языковой вопрос или математический? Если языковой, то, естественно, слово "некоторые" предполагает, что есть такие коты. А если математический, то в математическом языке нет слова "некоторые". Извольте говорить примерно так: существует кот, который ест спаржу.

Comment: Либо это тема формальной логики.

Comment: @Niemand *в математическом языке нет слова "некоторые"* — мне как математику немного странно это слышать :) В математике есть такое слово и оно используется в качестве квантора существования. Даже в выражении "рассмотрим некоторого сферического коня в вакууме" подразумевается, что такой конь [в определённом смысле] существует.

Comment: Я говорю о строгом языке. Вот и нужно использовать квантор существования – чтобы не возникало таких вопросов, как у автора. У меня тоже в дипломе есть слово "математик" )

Answer (score 6):

Про подмножества ничего не знаю и знать не хочу, зато вот нам явлены все лексические значения многозначного слова "некоторый":

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)

**НЕКОТОРЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; ***местоим. прил.*** **1.** Какой-то, точно не определённый. *Н-ое время все молчали. В некоторых местах ткань проела моль. Н-ое количество зерна оставили на сев.* **2.** Кое-какой, незначительный. *У неё был н. опыт. Он имел н-ое состояние. У фильма был н. успех.* **3. *только мн*.:** некоторые, -ых. Не все, отдельные. *Н-ые мои друзья ушли на пенсию. Н-ые платья вышли из моды. Н-ые сотрудники опоздали, а н-ые совсем не пришли на собрание.* ◊ **В некотором роде.** В какой-л. степени, несколько (обычно при желании скрыть истинное положение вещей). **Некоторым образом.** В какой-то степени. *Он некоторым образом артист.*

---

По поводу няшных котэ:

> ...Если я скажу "некоторые коты едят спаржу", означает ли это, что
>   обязательно должны быть коты, едящие спаржу или же высказывание
>   допускает ситуацию, при которой не будет найден ни один кот, поедающий
>   спаржу?

Обязательно-преобязательно должны быть коты, причём более одного, обожающие спаржу!

---

Другие примеры словоупотребления - [Малый академический словарь русского языка](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-8354.htm)

**1.**

Какой-то, точно не определенный.

*Писарь настолько потерялся, что некоторое время не мог выговорить ни одного слова.* Мамин-Сибиряк, Хлеб.

*Оба молчали и чувствовали некоторую неловкость.* Чехов, Степь.

**2.**

Кое-какой, незначительный.

*— А вы были в Москве, доктор? — Да, я имел там некоторую практику.* Лермонтов, Княжна Мери.

*— Имеете вы хотя бы некоторое состояние? — Никакого состояния покамест я не имею.* Достоевский, Идиот.

**3. *только мн. ч.***

Не все, отдельные.

{Городничий:} *Не угодно ли вам будет осмотреть теперь некоторые заведения в нашем городе?* Гоголь, Ревизор.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое, всё разъяснили!

Answer (score 0):

Это потрясающий вопрос который не имеет никакого отношения к лингвистике. Я уверен, что нет никакой известной нам силы, которая заставляет реальность подстраиваться под то, что говорит человек, как и человек, может не подстраиваться под реальность (внешнюю) в своей речи. Поэтому считаю, никто и ничто не обязано этих котов материализовать, если вы скажете эту фразу, и на момент её высказывания не окажется ни одного кота во всем мире поедающего спаржу.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения к лингвистике. Ну разве что косвенное, благодаря большому количеству грамматических ошибок.

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой ответ.